# How can I test a string against multiple others in Java?

Tags: java, string, comparison

> ```
> The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, String
> ```

I keep getting the above error message with the following `if` statement:

```java
String mGuess = Guess.getText().toString();
if (mGuess != "1" || "2" || "3" || "4" || "5" || "6" || "7" || "8" || "9" || "10") {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        "The number you entered was invalid. Please try again.",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, you should generally not be using `!=` to compare strings; use `equals()` instead. The `==` and `!=` operators will only test if the strings are identical objects; they do not test for equal values. Second, you need to expand the expression like this:

```
if (!mGuess.equals("1") || !mGuess.equals("2") || /* etc */) { . . .
```

Finally, this logic doesn't actually make any sense. The condition will always be true (`mGuess` will always be "not equal" to at least all but one of the test strings). You probably want:

```
if (!mGuess.equals("1") && !mGuess.equals("2") && /* etc */) { . . .
```

A more succinct way of doing this would be:

```
List<String> validStrings = Arrays.asList("1", "2", ...);
if (!validStrings.contains(mGuess)) { ...
```

(You could declare `validStrings` as a `static` class member to save creating one each time through the method. Also, see [the answer by assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15317932/535871) for how to use a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList` for the lookup; it will do the lookup faster.)

P.S. As mentioned by assylias and also by kcoppock in a comment, you should consider parsing the input as an `int` value and then doing a numeric test. The difference would be that parsing as an `int` would treat, say, "07" the same as "7". If you want to allow that, then this code will do the job:

```
boolean ok = false;
try {
    int guess = Integer.parseInt(mGuess);
    ok = guess >= 1 && guess <= 10;
} catch (NumberFormatException ignored) {
}
if (!ok) { . . .
```

Comment: Very good and thorough answer. As an aside, in the case where there are a large number of strings, a `HashSet` or similar might be a more efficient choice.

Comment: @JeremyRoman - Good point. I think [@assylias](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15317932/535871) made exactly that suggestion.

Comment: Indeed. As a further aside, this data structure never changes, and should probably be a `static final` member of the class.

Comment: Also, if it's always numeric, you could parse the input (guarded for NumberFormatExceptions of course) and then switch on that result. Would be much clearer. EDIT: Oops @assylias already suggested that. :)

Comment: @kcoppock - You would have to wrap the number conversion in a try/catch to deal with blank field or non-numeric input. To me, it's a toss-up whether that would be clearer. Also, OP may actually want to exclude input such as "07". On the other hand, if OP wants to treat "07" the same as "7", then parsing as an int is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Don't be afraid of regex. `if( !mGuess.matches( "([1-9]|10)" ) )` will take care of it.

Comment: @323go - Excellent point. The regex could even be `"0*([1-9]|10)"` to handle leading zeroes if OP wants to allow that.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make each condition explicit as already explained. A more compact way to write it would be:

```
Set<String> oneToTen = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10");

if (!oneToTen.contains(mGuess)) {
```

Alternatively, if you know that mGuess is a number, you could parse it to an integer first:

```
int guess = Integer.parseInt(mGuess);
if (guess < 0 || guess > 10) {
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The *cause* of the compiler error<sup>1</sup> is that the expression

```
mGuess != "1" || "2" || ..
```

is parsed equivalently to

```
((mGuess != "1") || "2") || ..
```

However, the type of `myGuess != "1"` is `boolean`, so the above expression is typed as

```
((boolean) || String) || String) || ..
```

but `boolean || String` is invalid, as per the compiler error:

> The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, String

---

<sup>1</sup> See one of the other answers for solutions.

Comment: +1 Amazing that none of the rest of us thought to explain the error message itself. It's worth pointing out that `||` is not defined for two `String` arguments, either.

Comment: @TedHopp No point trying to compete with your answer, you got that area nailed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `&&` to evaluate your negative expressions, use `.equals` for `String` comparisons, and have syntactically correct expressions in your `if` statement:

```
if (!mGuess.equals("1") && !mGuess.equals("2") && ...
```

Also see: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)